# Calculate local derivatives with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

A have a CSV like the below, where it's composed by three columns, `ix` , `iy` and `iz`, which denotes the point (x,y,z) where the variable `u'` is calculated. The original CSV ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSdtC7cxi0zIEpMcwpEr1LuXIm9Lry9M/view?usp=sharing)) contains 128^3 rows, describing all possible combinations of `ix, iy` `iz`:

```
i,ix,iz,iy,u'
0,1,1,1,-0.8696748576752853
1,1,1,2,2.3557976585107454
2,1,1,3,0.47209618683697663
3,1,1,4,-1.930481713597933
4,1,1,5,-1.7868247414530511
5,1,1,6,-0.5603642778861779
6,1,1,7,0.24540750240253573
7,1,1,8,0.5505270314521304
8,1,1,9,-0.1954277406567968
9,1,1,10,-1.3521265193776344
```

I would like to take the derivative of `u'` respect to `iy`, in other words, calculate $\frac{u(x,y+1,z) - u(x,y,z}{dy}$. In my first attempt, I tried somenthing like this (where dy = 8.68)

```
dudy=[];
for y in np.arange(1,128):
    for x in np.arange(1,129):
        for z in np.arange(1,129):
            dev= (df[(df["ix"] == x) & (df["iy"] == y+1) & (df["iz"] == z)]["u'"].values - 
                    df[(df["ix"] == x) & (df["iy"] == y) & (df["iz"] == z)]["u'"].values)/dy
            dudy.append(dev)
```

In another words, for some fixed value of `iy`, I found all the combinations of `ix` and `iz`, and all the combinations when `iy+1`, and then performed the quotient. The result it's seems right for a few lines, but for the whole data (128^3 rows), takes an absurd time to evaluate the code. I guess this occurs because before calculate the quotient, the code search for all the combinations of `ix` and `iz`, and for some reason this seems not much intelligent.

How can I improve this? There's another way to evaluate this kind of operation? A built-in function?

Comment: What do you want to have for starting point `iy=1`? Please checkout my answer. This should do the work except when `iy=1` which you can easily replace with whatever you like (probable `NaN`)

Comment: I will check, but it doesn't seems right because you don't use the dy value. But I will check...

Comment: isn't dy=1? You can divide that column to dy anyways if it is not one. Please find my edit regarding that in the post

Comment: I would like to set NaN for the last point, `iy = 128`, so then I can compare the first rows of my solution with yours. As you can see, in my code  `iy` goes from 1 to 128, because the code fails when achieve `iy` = 129 and make 129 + 1.

Comment: Added the output of your code vs. proposed solution in the post. fixed the shift and NaN you wanted into the code. Please find the edit. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, because I need the derivatives in their right index. But I can change this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I already fixed that. Please checkout the code again. Thank you

Comment: do you mean `df.sort_values(['ix','iz','iy']` vs. `df.sort_values(['iz','ix','iy']`? I do not think it matters in your case since derivative is not w.r.t them. When ix and iz change, iy=128 and you are setting it to NaN anyways. I would recommend double checking the edge cases to be sure btw.

Comment: Yes, I thinked this too. In my code does't import the order of the for loops x and z. Thanks again, helped me a lot.

Comment: I realized you can set period=-1 in diff function and divide by -dy and avoid shifting up. Please checkout edit for faster solution. Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by `ix,iz,iy` (in this order) and take diff to create derivative column `der_y`:

```
df.sort_values(['ix','iz','iy'], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='first')
dy=1
df['der_y'] = df["u'"].diff(periods=-1)/-dy
#you will need to replace when `iy==128` with your desired output (probably NaN)
df.loc[df['iy']==128,'der_y'] = None
```

output of this code:

```
   i  ix  iz  iy        u'     der_y
0  0   1   1   1 -0.869675  3.225473
1  1   1   1   2  2.355798 -1.883701
2  2   1   1   3  0.472096 -2.402578
3  3   1   1   4 -1.930482  0.143657
4  4   1   1   5 -1.786825  1.226460
5  5   1   1   6 -0.560364  0.805772
6  6   1   1   7  0.245408  0.305120
7  7   1   1   8  0.550527 -0.745955
8  8   1   1   9 -0.195428 -1.156699
9  9   1   1  10 -1.352127       NaN
```

output of for loop provided in the question:

```
[[ 3.22547252]
 [-1.88370147]
 [-2.4025779 ]
 [ 0.14365697]
 [ 1.22646046]
 [ 0.80577178]
 [ 0.30511953]
 [-0.74595477]
 [-1.15669878]]
```